# How can I make a siren noise in Python?

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to make a siren sound in python with beeps, but had no success..

I'm trying something like

```
winsound.Beep(700,500)
winsound.Beep(710,500)
winsound.Beep(720,500)
...
```

It's a better way to do it? And play it?

Without external files...

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record a high quality siren as a WAV file ([Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is a nice tool for this task, and might even provide the right mix of sound generators for this) and use `PlaySound`.

```
winsound.PlaySound('siren.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

You could also bundle it into the script as a string to avoid having a separate file:

```
siren = base64.b64decode('''
    <base64-encoded data>
    ''')
winsound.PlaySound(siren, winsound.SND_MEMORY)
```

To create the data for `siren`, run the WAV file through a base64 encoder (e.g., [here](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/base64/) is a basic command-line tool — the download includes a win32 exe) and paste the output into the `siren` string. Base64 isn't a requirement, by the way; it's just a convenient way to embed binary data into a Python source file.

Comment: but then I will be using external files

Comment: No you won't. The second form uses a Python string directly, and the first version of my answer said as much.

Comment: No probs. I've amended the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Put this in your answer - http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp - it was very helpfull =)

Comment: you can infact embed any file format as a python string, using the base64 encode; and use it your desires.

Answer (score 2):

I remember using something similar on QBASIC when I was still a kid:

```
DO
FOR n = -180 TO 180 STEP .1
f = 440 + 50 * SIN(n)
SOUND f, 1
NEXT
LOOP
```

`SOUND f, 1` should be the same thing as `winsound.Beep`, with pitch and duration. It used to work great but since I took the snippet [here](http://www.codepedia.com/1/QbasicFAQ_SoundTutorial) I'm not sure I did exactly this way.

It's just to give you the idea..